# Meteor.js dealing with a MongoDB object and saving changes

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm using the following code on meteor:

```
            var game = Games.findOne({_id:gameId});
            if(game.status == 'waiting'){
                game.status == 'canceled';
            }
```

Basically I'm fetching an object from a collection, making some changes to it, and now I want to save it to the database, how to do this? Is there something like a .save() method?

I'm coming from PHP so I might be totally missing the point, but in Laravel I can just fetch from database, work with the object and when done just update it on the database. Can I use the same workflow in meteor? How?

Comment: Btw you probably want to use `=` instead of `==` in `game.status == 'canceled';`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `update` method.

Code should be like :

```
var game = Games.findOne({_id:gameId});

if(game.status == 'waiting'){
      Games.update({_id:gameId},{$set : {status: 'canceled'}});
}
```

**Caution:** This will only work on client side when `insecure` package is still included. You should call a method for CRUD operations on DB in production.

Answer (score 0):

After you are done working with the object you can save it like this

```
var game = Games.findOne({_id:gameId});

if (game.status == 'waiting') {
    game.status = 'canceled';
}

// .. change more stuff in `game`

Games.update({_id: game._id}, {$set: game});
```

---

The difference between this and [Ankit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39160354/5811984) is that in my version the whole object gets updated, while in Ankit's only `status`. It is probably better to use his way if you are only going to update one parameter, and mine otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

As the others answered the meteor collections doesn't have the workflow you expect, but there is an ORM package for meteor called astronomy that does it the way you want, so you might be more productive if you try it out (https://github.com/jagi/meteor-astronomy)

```
var game = Games.findOne({_id:gameId});
if(game.status == 'waiting'){
   game.status = 'canceled';
}
game.save()
```